# Query for Parse is not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is giving me an error. I have attached a screenshot of what the error looks like.
[image]

```
class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var users = [""]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Printing the currentUser name
        print(PFUser.currentUser()!)

        var query = PFUser.query()

        query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity : true)

            for object in objects {
                var user : PFUser = object as PFUser

                self.users.append(user.username)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be how you are declaring your `users` array. Try this.

```
class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var users = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Printing the currentUser name
        print(PFUser.currentUser()!)

        var query = PFUser.query()

        query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            self.users = [String]()

            if let parseUsers = objects as? [PFUser] {
                for u in parseUsers {
                    //parseUsers is now an array of PFUser
                    self.users.append(u.username)
                }
            } 
        })
    }
```

Also you cannot cast your users like that. Try this:

```
if let parseUsers = objects as? [PFUser] {
    //parseUsers is now an array of PFUser
}
```

Comment: I changed that and I still am having an error. `Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject])!, NSError!) -> Void to expected argument type PFQueryArrayResultBlock`

Comment: I got rid of the cast error. Now it's just the error with the `AnyObject`

Comment: Please note that i've answered your original question, so please mark it as so. I'm happy to help with your other error in a private chat

Comment: How do we do a private chat?